# Why did I still get MySQL errno 2013 Lost connection during query error even I had MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT on

Tags: mysql, reconnect

Like setup MySQL connection with MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT is true in this way

```
 my_bool reconnect = true;
 mysql_options(ptrMYSQL, MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT, &reconnect);
```

then raised one `SELECT` immediately, log file shows less than 1ms, performed OK.

295ms later, after did some other work, the process raised another query with the same `ptrMYSQL`, this one failed for the reason

> errno 2013 error Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Since I had the AUTO RECONNECT option on, how can MySQL query failed in such way?

This is what timeout variables look like:

```
mysql> show variables like '%timeout%';
+------------------------------+-----------+
| Variable_name                | Value     |
+------------------------------+-----------+
| connect_timeout              | 10        |
| delayed_insert_timeout       | 300       |
| have_statement_timeout       | YES       |
| innodb_flush_log_at_timeout  | 1         |
| innodb_lock_wait_timeout     | 8         |
| innodb_rollback_on_timeout   | OFF       |
| interactive_timeout          | 1800      |
| lock_wait_timeout            | 31536000  |
| net_read_timeout             | 30        |
| net_write_timeout            | 60        |
| rpl_semi_sync_master_timeout | 999999999 |
| rpl_stop_slave_timeout       | 31536000  |
| slave_net_timeout            | 30        |
| wait_timeout                 | 1800      |
+------------------------------+-----------+
14 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And the version:

```
mysql> select version();
+------------+
| version()  |
+------------+
| 5.7.17-log |
+------------+
```

Comment: Did the query overrun `max_allowed_packet`?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot No, not even close :-),